# Related with the performance of these codes? One being very fast and other exceeding the Time limit

Tags: c++, performance

I came across a problem on Codechef! Well, I was able to formulate a Dynamic programming solution to it but it only passed one third of the test cases!

When I came across a solution of author , it was highly close to mine! But even after trying (every possible logical changes to my code ) My solution isn't working and not passing test cases!

My code(I have to post it as a whole as I cannot simply understand why is it so slow!)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int A[5001];
long long DP[5001][5001];
int T,i,j;
int N,K,l;
int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(;T--;)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&N,&K);
        for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
                scanf("%d",&A[i]);
 //       for(i=1;i<=K;i++)
 //           DP[0][i]=INT_MIN;

       for(i=0;i<=N;i++)
            for(j=1;j<=K;j++)
                DP[i][j]=INT_MIN;

        for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
            {
                int temp=0,low;
                for(l=i;l>=1;l--)
                {
                    if(temp|A[l] >temp)
                    {
                        low=min(l,K);
                        temp|=A[l];
                        for(j=1;j<=low;j++)
                            DP[i][j]=max(DP[l-1][j-1]+temp,DP[i][j]);

                    }
                }
            }
        printf("%lld\n",DP[N][K]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What have I tried?

Using cin cout with `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);` instead of scanf printf. Using memset to clear the DP array! Declaring variables , global instead of local ( They were the differences between my code and the author s Code). Then I tried submitting the author's code just for checking whether it really works or not . It does !

Initially I had a Memoized version, I changed it to DP and still it doesn't work.

I am using for loops only just because in terms of performance they are considered better than while loops!

NOTE:I can change the setting of INT_MIN to 0 too and I have tried that too. Doesn't work!

**AUTHOR's SOLUTION**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define rf freopen("in.in", "r", stdin)
#define wf freopen("out.out", "w", stdout)
#define rep(i, s, n) for(int i=int(s); i<=int(n); ++i)
using namespace std;
const int mx = 1e5+10;

int n, t, k;
int a[mx];
long long calc[5111][5111];

int main()
{
    //rf;// wf;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        memset(calc, 0, sizeof calc);

        scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
        rep(i, 1, n)
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);

        rep(i, 1, n)
        {
            int cur = 0, next = 0;
            for(int j = i; j; --j)
            {
                next = cur | a[j];
                if(cur == next)
                    continue;

                rep(l, 1, min(k-1, j-1))
                    calc[i][l+1] = max(calc[j-1][l]+next, calc[i][l+1]);

                cur = next;
            }
            calc[i][1] = cur;
        }
        printf("%lld\n", calc[n][k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot post images due to reputation, but My solution exceeds every test case of 2nd and 3rd subtask.

Just in case , if you need problem statement [Problem(codechef)](http://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFAOR/) but I dont think it is needed in comparing these codes!

Comment: If you downvote, Please do tell me the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care with operator precedence:

```
temp|A[l] >temp
```

will be evaluated as

```
temp|(A[l] >temp)
```

Comment: How can I  further increase the performance of my  Code? 
That indeed makes the code do what it was intended to! I have been stuck at this since yesterday

Comment: `++i` could be a little bit faster than `i++`, but apart from that I don't see anything slow.

Comment: I used memset instead of loop ! It is indeed much faster brings down the time by almost 1.5 seconds!